# Tumblr API / Dashes in property names

Tags: json, backbone.js, tumblr, marionette

I'm using Backbone and Marionette to display a list of tumblr-posts. I want to use the thumbnail available in the JSON api, but this presents me with a problem. The url I want to fetch is called `"photo-url-100": "http://blablablablabla"`. Normally in JS I would use `parentObject['photo-url-100']`, but as I'm iterating through all items with Backbone / Marionette, there is no root node available as far as I'm aware (all properties are directly available, so for example `<%= id %>` instead of `<%= post.id %>`. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I should handle this?

Some clarification: I'm using MarionetteJS. As per Tumblr's doc I've added their "API" (in my case http://gentletruths.tumblr.com/api/read/json) as a script-tag in my header, effectively "bootstrapping" it. I process it as a collection, and each post as a model. This collection is then handled by a `Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView`, and each model by a `Backbone.Marionette.ItemView`. So in my `ItemView` template (below) the `id` works (as a reference), but the `photo-url-100` doesn't.

```
<script id="instagram_item_template" type="text/template">
    <a href="#" class="photos__frame">
        <span class="caption"><%= id %></span>
        <img src="<%= photo-url-100 %>" alt="" class="photos__photo">
    </a>
</script>
```

I've consulted Marionette's annotated source (render function here: http://marionettejs.com/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-188), but I'm not sure how to properly read this and deduce how the data is made available.

Comment: can you post the part of your code where the iteration is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering a `_.template()`, simply wrap your `parentObject` inside another object:

```
var compiled = _.template("<img id=\"<%= post.id %>\" src=\"<%= post['photo-url-100'] %>\">");
compiled({ 'post': parentObject });
```

**Edit**:

Your template:

```
<script id="instagram_item_template" type="text/template">
  <a href="#" class="photos__frame">
    <span class="caption"><%= post.id %></span>
    <img src="<%= post['photo-url-100'] %>" alt="" class="photos__photo">
  </a>
</script>
```

Rendering template:

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  template: function(data){
    return _.template($('#instagram_item_template').html(), { 'post': data })
  }
});
```

Comment: I've expanded on my question a bit to make things more clear, care to take a look again?

Comment: @Steven can you post the code where you initialize the collection with the tumblr data?

Comment: I've overridden the template function, works. Here is my tumblr-data init code: https://gist.github.com/StevenLangbroek/7466b51e2db56ad898cb